# How to output from php system(wget=...) to a single refreshing line or progress bar?

Tags: php, wget

I am currently working on a simple page, that downloads a whole folder from a ftp server  after the user enters the ID of the folder. After tinkering for a while I got it to work with the php system() command calling wget, as I couldn't find anything about recursive downloading with curl.

The files are sometimes quite large (3+ gb).

I now need to "beautify" the output so that the site doesn't get cluttered with thousands of lines of the wget output. And the user knows when the download has finished.

Is there a way to only display the last line of the system() output? Or even better a progress bar?

Heres the code I've got so far:

```
    <?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");
function disable_ob() {
    // Turn off output buffering
    ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
    // Turn off PHP output compression
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
    // Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
    ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    // Clear, and turn off output buffering
    while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
        // Get the curent level
        $level = ob_get_level();
        // End the buffering
        ob_end_clean();
        // If the current level has not changed, abort
        if (ob_get_level() == $level) break;
    }
    // Disable apache output buffering/compression
    if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) {
        apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
        apache_setenv('dont-vary', '1');
    }
}
// tell php to automatically flush after every output
// including lines of output produced by shell commands
disable_ob();


$clonestr1 = 'wget -r ftp://someftpserver/' . $_POST["jobid"];

$clonestr2 = '/zip/* -P /outputpath/"jobid/ 2>&1 ';


$complete = $clonestr1 . $clonestr2;

system($complete);
?>
```

The output right now looks like this:

```
    Resolving someftpserver (someftpserver)... 
    Connecting to someftpserver (someftpserver)
    connected.
    Logging in as ftp_user ... Logged in!
    ==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
    ==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /folder/ ... done.
    ==> PASV ... done.    ==> LIST ... done.
    
         0K                                                        3.26K=0.07s
    
    2020-07-12 05:15:40 (3.26 KB/s) - '/outputfolder/.listing' saved [217]
    
    Removed '/outputfolder/.listing'.
    --2020-07-12 05:15:40--  ftp://someftpserver/file.zip
               => '/outputfolder/file.zip'
    ==> CWD not required.
    ==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR file.zip ... done.
    Length: 3293886663 (3.1G)
    
         0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 99.9K 8h56m
        50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  278K 6h4m
       100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 11.3M 4h4m
       150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 11.1M 3h4m
       200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  285K 3h5m
       250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 11.1M 2h35m
       300K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 11.1M 2h13m
       350K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 11.1M 1h57m
.
.
.
```